# Is there a way to enforce type definitions in VS Code for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tslint

Is there a way to have VS Code highlight whenever methods don't have return types or variables don't have types etc when using Typescript? Wanting it to be stricter to enforce things.

I've come across this as an answer in an older Stack Overflow post:
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/

However it requires tslint and that I believe is being deprecated which may or may not explain why the plugin in the link above does not seem to function. Are there some new rules to replace this that can be placed in the tsconfig.json perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

tslint is deprecated, for now the best alternative is [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint), there's also a guide on how to migrate from tslint to eslint lies in [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/ROADMAP.md), you can easily find corresponding rules to `typedef`